# How to access a block of memory as a file object in Python 2.5?

Tags: python, ctypes, python-2.5

I would like to get a file object for a block of memory in Python 2.5 under Windows.(for some reasons I cannot use newer versions for this tasks.)

So as input I do have a `pointer` and a `size` and let's assume that I need only read only access.

In case you'll wonder, I got these by using ctypes and I need to make them available  to a function that expects a filehandler (read-only).

I considered using `cStringIO` but in order to create such an object I need a `string` object.

Comment: you have a pointer ?? what does a pointer mean in python ?

Comment: meanss the same thing as in C - an in process memory address where your data is. How to get to said data is a whole different problem.

Comment: Added details, as requested :)

Comment: beware that a python fileobject is a python only construct: it does not always have system file handle associated with it.

Answer (score 6):

You should use ctypes in there.   As of Python 2.5 ctypes where already on the standard  library, so a "win" situation for you.

With ctypes you can construct a python object representing a higher level pointe doing this:

```
import ctypes 
integer_pointer_type = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)
my_pointer = integer_pointer_type.from_address(your_address)
```

You can then address the memory contents as a Python indexed object, like
print my_pointer[0]

This won't give you a "file like interface" - although it would be trivial to wrap a class with a "read" and "seek" methods around such an object:

```
class MyMemoryFile(object):
    def __init__(self, pointer, size=None):
         integer_pointer_type = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uchar)
         self.pointer = integer_pointer_type.from_address(your_address)
         self.cursor = 0
         self.size = size

    def seek(self, position, whence=0):
         if whence == 0:
              self.cursor = position
         raise NotImplementedError
    def read(size=None):
         if size is None:
             res =  str(self.pointer[cursor:self.size])
             self.cursor = self.size
         else:
             res = str(self.pointer[self.cursor:self.cursor + size]
             self.cursor += size
         return res
```

(not tested - write me if it does not work - can be fixed)

Please note that attempts to read the memory beyond the space allocated for your data structure will have the exact same effects as doing so in C: in most cases,a segmentation fault.

Comment: I didn't test it as well, but I think that giving a read size greater than `self.size` is bad. Better check it. And maybe put the `self.cursor` stuff immendiately before the `return res`, in the form of `self.cursor += len(res)` - this covers all cases.

Answer (score 1):

from the `ctypes` documentation, it appears that you can get a string from an address in memory, using [the `ctypes.string_at()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.string_at).

the problem is that a string is not mutable, that means that you won't be able to modify the resulting string from python. to have a mutable buffer in python, you will need to call the [`ctypes.create_string_buffer()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.create_string_buffer) from python.